# Optimization of functionals with constraints

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, calculus-of-variations, integral-operators

I have a minimization problem as follows:

$\min\left( \int_0^1\int_0^1\beta(t)\beta(s)G_1(t, s)dtds\right)^{1/2}+\left( \int_0^1\int_0^1\beta(t)\beta(s)G_2(t, s)dtds\right)^{1/2} $

$\texttt{s.t.}\;\;\;\;\;\;\int_0^1\beta(t)\mu(t)dt=1,$

where $G_1$ and $G_2$ are symmetric positive definite functions which are also continuous and uniformly bounded on $\left[ 0, 1\right]^2$, $\beta$ and $\mu\neq 0$ are both in $L_2\left[ 0, 1\right]$.

(The discrete version of this problem can be solved by covex optimization and the solution can be found by certain algorithms.)

The existence of the minimizer is not a problem. I am looking for a way(an algorithm or some other methods) to find the solution.

One solution I can come up with is that for kernel function $G_1$ and $G_2$, they admits spectral decomposition by Mercer's theorem, and the corresponding two basis systems are orthogonal in $L^2$. If $G_1=G_2$, then the problem can be tranformed to the convex optimization problem in infinite dimension and the solution is promising. However, when $G_1\neq G_2$, the representation of $\beta$ is not unique because of different basis functions and the relation between these two representations are unknown.

Another way I can think of is the simultaneous diagonalization of two operators, but it hardly works since there are no other conditions on two eigensystems.

Could anyone give some thoughts on how to find the solution? Thank you!